# GetRequiredService without ParameterInjection or Constructor Injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor

I am using DotNet Core 3.1 with Balzor Serverside. From where do i need import the container.
I have the following Problem, I want to access an Service from inside an Function

```
public static async Task<SetDataViewAction> Async(MDataView dataView)
{
  IDataViewService dataViewService = ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService<IDataViewService>(How i get the Provider?);
 }
```

Can anyone can help me?

Comment: Why in the function?  Just inject it in the constructor.